# Reading integer array from properties file, using @Value annotation

Tags: spring, properties, annotations, spring-annotations

I have the following in my properties file,

```
increments = 10,20,30
```

I want to read these properties in my POJO,

```
@Value("#{'${increments}'.split(',')}")
List<Integer> increments;

List<Integer> getIncrements(){
  return increments;
}
```

And then use this POJO in another class,

```
List<Integer> increments = pojo.getIncrements();
```

However, in the last call, I get a conversion error - String to Integer.
To overcome this, I am reading the array as a String array, and converting it to Integer array explicitly in the getIncrements() method.

Is there a way to read an array of integers from a properties file into a POJO without explicit type conversion?

Comment: Instead of `List<Integer>` try `int[]` or `Integer[]` with just a `@Value("${increments"}`. Spring should be able to do the type conversion for you that way.

Comment: What version of Spring are you using? I think that such issues were fixed in some minor iteration

Comment: @geoand I am using Spring 3.1.0

Comment: @ufdeveloper Try upgrading to Spring 3.1.4. If that doesn't work and you have the ability to upgrade to Spring 3.2, then go for Spring 3.2.9 and let me know

Comment: @M.Deinum It works with your approach, but I still need to convert the array to a list explicitly. It is much cleaner than what I was doing though. I'll try geoand's suggestion to check if its possible to do it without explicit conversion.